# How to send push notification at a segment with Mainline

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I'm currently using Mainline's API to send push notifications. https://api.mainline-tech.com/
But even if I understand how to send to all users, I failed to find in documentation how to create a segment or group to send push notifications at only some users ? If someone use Mainline and Know how to do it ...

Answer (score 0):

Hummm ... it seems Mainline's API includes a "Group" Section :) ... So that you can easily create a segment with only some users using tags / data / geoloc ..

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer unless you can provide how to do it with some examples or code! :)